# How to combine rowediting and rowexpander together correctly in extjs?

Tags: extjs

I am developing a web application in **ExtJS**. The application is a `grid` where some of the grid`s rows can be expanded to show supplementary information as a nested grid. And user can edit rows in parent grid.

But I have problems with it. The nested `grid` is normally rendered , but when I want to update one of the field nested grid disappear.

There is testing version of my application and some screenshots.

**The Code** ( below you can find screens)

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
        fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
        data: {
            'items': [{
                    'name': 'Lisa',
                    "email": "lisa@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-111-1224"
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Bart',
                    "email": "bart@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1234"
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Homer',
                    "email": "home@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1244"
                },
                {
                    'name': 'Marge',
                    "email": "marge@simpsons.com",
                    "phone": "555-222-1254"
                }
            ]
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'items'
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Simpsons',
        plugins: [{
                ptype: 'rowexpander',
                pluginId: 'courseListGridExpander',
                expandOnDblClick: false,
                selectRowOnExpand: false,
                enableCaching: false,
                rowBodyTpl: ['']
            },
            Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
                clicksToMoveEditor: 2,
                autoCancel: false

            })
        ],
        viewConfig: {
            listeners: {
                expandbody: function(rowNode, record, expandbody) {
                    var targetId = 'SessionInstructionGridRow';
                    if (Ext.getCmp(targetId + "_grid") == null) {
                        var sessionInstructionGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                            renderTo: targetId,
                            id: targetId + "_grid",
                            title: 'Nested One',
                            columns: [{
                                    header: 'Halo',
                                    flex: 1
                                },
                                {
                                    header: 'Halo 2',
                                    flex: 1
                                }
                            ]
                        });
                        rowNode.grid = sessionInstructionGrid;
                        sessionInstructionGrid.getEl().swallowEvent(['mouseover', 'mousedown', 'click', 'dblclick', 'onRowFocus']);
                        sessionInstructionGrid.fireEvent("bind", sessionInstructionGrid, {
                            ClientSessionId: record.get('ClientSessionId')
                        });
                    }
                },
                celldblclick: function(gr, td, cellIndex, record) {
                    //alert("@@@");
                }
            }
        },

        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                editor: {
                    allowBlank: false
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            },
            {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone'
            }
        ],
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
        text: 'Hello',
        handler: function() {

        }
    })
});
```

[image: nested grid loaded normally]

[image: when i updated row my nested grid dissapeared]

Comment: What version of Extjs are you using?

Comment: Actually I am using 4.2.0

Comment: is it possible to do such combinations in extjs 4.2.0 ? may be , should I seek other variants ?

Comment: I would suggest not embedding another grid in the row like you have done, it just looks ugly and is not really what that expansion row area is typically used for. Take a look at the examples here - http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/grid/grid-plugins.html See if they give you some idea's

Comment: yes, those examples are great, indeed. But the examples you have given to me are created by Ext.XTemplate. I need a such  nested grid with toolbar button that I can add new row by clicking "Add" button for example. it could be done but , when i add rowediting plugin matters goes wrong

Answer (score 1):

I would give the [ComponentRowExpander](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?280406-Ext.ux.ComponentRowExpander-component-in-grid-row-expander) plugin a try. It's intended to insert any component in a rowexpander - so it should work with a grid, too.